# SQL to query convert chrome time stamp to epoch

Tags: sql, sqlite, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying query the Chrome history database and return the chromium timestamp to be human readable and include milliseconds, alternative options I've tried return the incorrect year, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

For example for example 14/06/2022 10:05:30.25

SELECT
u.url AS URL, u.title AS Title, u.visit_count As "Visit Count", datetime(u.last_visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') As "Last Visited Date Time", datetime(v.visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS "Visited Date Time"
FROM urls u, visits v
WHERE u.id = v.url

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I would like the chrome date 13297180766824287 to be returned in the following format 2022-05-16 14:19:26.82

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458406/what-is-the-format-of-chromes-timestamps