# Converting Chrome Timestamp in Go

Tags: macos, google-chrome, go

I am trying to convert timestamps from the local Chrome sqlite db to local time using Go. I know that these timestamps are meant to be [microseconds from 1601/01/01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458406/what-is-the-format-of-chromes-timestamps).

Checking the values I'm getting for `lastVisitTime` in the following program on [this Chrome timestamp conversion website](https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit), I appear to be retrieving them from the database correctly.

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"

    "github.com/local_library/comp"
)

var (
    dbPath           = comp.Expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History")
    chromeEpochStart = time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
)

const (
    driverName = "sqlite3"
    tmpPath    = "/tmp/History"
    query      = `
SELECT
    last_visit_time
FROM 
    urls
ORDER BY
    last_visit_time DESC
LIMIT 5
`
)

func main() {
    // Copy to tmp to unlock
    err := comp.Copy(dbPath, tmpPath)
    comp.MustBeNil(err)

    db, err := sql.Open(driverName, tmpPath)
    comp.MustBeNil(err)
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    comp.MustBeNil(err)
    for rows.Next() {
        var lastVisitTime int64
        rows.Scan(&lastVisitTime)
        d := time.Duration(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(lastVisitTime))
        t := chromeEpochStart.Add(d)
        fmt.Println(t, lastVisitTime)
    }

    err = rows.Close()
    comp.MustBeNil(err)
    err = rows.Err()
    comp.MustBeNil(err)
}
```

But for some reason, my `.Add(d)` is setting the times *before* 1601, which I have never seen before.

```
1439-07-05 20:00:21.462742384 +0000 UTC 13350512095172294
1439-07-05 19:58:20.377916384 +0000 UTC 13350511974087468
1439-07-05 19:57:58.539932384 +0000 UTC 13350511952249484
1439-07-05 19:57:48.539540384 +0000 UTC 13350511942249092
1439-07-05 19:52:09.587445384 +0000 UTC 13350511603296997
```

What's happening here and, more importantly, how do I do this correctly?

Comment: 13350511952249484 * time.Microsecond overflows int64 (the underlying type for time.Duration): https://go.dev/play/p/8mQRRwT0gSt

Comment: Unfortunate that I didn't get a panic for this in my code. Thank you. –

Comment: Arithmetic overflow is not a cause for panic.

Comment: It causes a compiler error for the code @Peter linked. If something causes a compiler error, it seems reasonable that it would cause a panic if encountered in runtime.

Comment: There is no panic. In my code compilation fails because I used constants, not variables. Constants are checked by the compiler. Variables overflow. That's why you get dates before 1601; the duration becomes negative.

Comment: I understand that is the *current* behavior. What I was proposing is that it *shouldn't* be, along the lines of https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31500. But I can see the proposal was ultimately rejected on ambiguous grounds. I can see both sides of the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868863/converting-chrome-timestamp-in-go#comment137278299_77868863) pointing out the overflow in my original code, I found a different approach.

If you convert the Chrome start date to `UnixMicro()`, you get the negative offset from regular epoch time:

```golang
chromeMicroOffset := time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).UnixMicro()
fmt.Println(chromeMicroOffset)
```

```
-11644473600000000
```

Adding these to the database values and converting them to nanoseconds in `time.Unix()` gets you the correct time in UTC:

```golang
microFromEpoch := chromeMicroOffset + lastVisitTime
t := time.Unix(0, microFromEpoch*1000)
```

A full example converted to Pacific time:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var (
    chromeMicroOffset = time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).UnixMicro()
)

func main() {
    chromeTimestamp := int64(13350516239099543)

    microFromEpoch := chromeMicroOffset + chromeTimestamp
    t := time.Unix(0, microFromEpoch*1000)
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t.In(loc))
}
```

```
2024-01-23 12:43:59.099543 -0800 PST
```